# Looking for a Harry Potter story where Harry figures out his magic and runs away as a child

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

I can't remember a definite year for when I read it, or when it was published, other than that it was between 3-8 years ago. I originally found the story on fanfiction.net.

In the story, Harry discovers he can do magic, learns to fly based off of Peter Pan as well as some other tricks like shrinking and enlarging things, and leaves the Dursleys. After that, he travels around, learns more about magic, and there's a lot of world-building. One of the incidents I remember is when he gets caught by some spider being and makes a bet with it to get his freedom. Another one is where he accidentally finds a dormant god and wakes them by kissing them, like how Snow White and Sleeping Beauty were awoken. There's also a giant robotic penguin made by some mad genius wizard that's obsessed with penguins.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! These might help you to improve your question; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [How to ask a good (Fanfic) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11922/how-to-ask-a-good-fanfic-story-id-question)

Answer (score 5):

I believe this is [The Boy and the Beginning](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/9075842/1/The-Boy-and-the-Beginning)

- Learning to fly from [Peter Pan](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/9075842/1/The-Boy-and-the-Beginning)

  > Then he thought, suddenly, of his favorite story, Peter Pan, and wished dearly in that moment, that he could just fly away into the sky and hide in the clouds where no one would reach him. 
  >   That's when a sudden rushing sensation filled him, a feeling of intense, though not uncomfortable warmth and weightlessness filled him
- He travels to a lot of places, like [Spain](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/9075842/6/The-Boy-and-the-Beginning)

  > By the time the sun had set, and the stars were peeking out in the wee hours close to midnight, Harry rose into the sky above the city and continued on his journey to explore Spain.
- Wakes a [storm god](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/9075842/11/The-Boy-and-the-Beginning) up with a kiss

  > What was his conclusion? The only solution that Harry knew of too waking someone up from an enchanted/magical seeming sleep that was a popular cure in a fair amount of fairy tales. A kiss. Harry grimaced. He hadn't particularly enjoyed his first kiss ever coming from the storm deity; still, if it was the only way, then he would just suck it up and do it.
- He makes a deal with a [spider](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/9075842/12/The-Boy-and-the-Beginning)

  > The spider agreed, and again pondered the conundrum before he declared magnanimously. "Then a reward you shall have Moonskin, you have only to name what you want such as riches, fine foods, grand palaces and beautiful women or men, when you get old enough to want such things."  Freedom," Harry stated clearly, "let it be the ultimate desire of all beings be the reward."
- A guy that really likes [penguins](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/9075842/8/The-Boy-and-the-Beginning)...

  > Harry blinked the Penguin squawked again. 
  >   "As you have no doubt witnessed, this handsome gift you have been given was a most serious and challenging project that took several decades of my life to accomplish. The ability to turn one's enemies into penguins!" The man chortled, looking quite pleased. "Ah yes, penguins! Such admirable creatures! And by turning your enemies into them, it only betters the world!

For anyone curious, I found this at the bottom of the first search results when googling: harry potter "fly" "peter pan" site:fanfiction.net -crossover

Comment: Good lord, the writing in those snippets is *atrocious*. This is why I don't read fan fiction.

Comment: @Martha There's always going to be good and bad ones, just like in any sort of media. The good ones make it worth it though.